# Run-time error '1004': with .Formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the formula below in cell L52 and fill this formula down through L54 and am getting this error. The formula works fine when typed into the cell, but the VBA is not working.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("L52").Formula = "=IF(C12="","",IF(LEFT($K52,1)*1=8,"",CHOOSE(LEFT($K52,1),$C52,$D52,$E52,$F52,$G52,$H52,$J52)))"


ActiveSheet.Range("L52").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("L52:L64"), Type:=xlFillValues
```

Comment: Quotes inside a string need to be doubled-up to escape them

Comment: `"=IF(C12="""","""",IF(LEFT($K52,1)*1=8,"""",CHOOSE(LEFT($K52,1),$C52,$D52,$E52,$F52,$G52,$H52,$J52)))"`

Comment: Could try this? or the comment listed abose works for you? `ActiveSheet.Range("L52").Formula = "=IF(C12="""", """", IF(LEFT($K52,1)*1=8, """", CHOOSE(LEFT($K52,1),$C52,$D52,$E52,$F52,$G52,$H52,$J52)))"
ActiveSheet.Range("L52:L54").FillDown`